# Unmask textbox password with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox for user to enter positive integer. User enters a lot of entries many times. Overtime, textbox has list of previous entries, when you start typing something similar to previous entry.
Sometimes, user accidentally select those previous entries. I know this one of browser's features.

> Is there anyway to clear these previous entries from javascript, or jQuery?

So, I'm thinking of using textbox (password mode) then unmask it with Javascript or jQuery. I think browser won't keep anything if textbox is for password.

> How can I unmask textbox password with Javascript or jQuery if it's the right approach for this problem?

What I'm doing is to clear the history of the textbox I have on an ASPX page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a master page, you can turn form autocomplete off like in the child page that you have that Textbox control on like this:

On page load event:

```
 >Me.Form.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off")
```

Also add this attribute to your Textbox AutoCompleteType="Disabled"

Answer (score 5):

I think you are talking about the autocomplete feature - the browser gives a list of entries entered previously.

If you don't want it, then simple use `autocomplete="off"`. There is no need of javascript (and therefore jquery)

Autocomplete can be turned off for one particular field or for an entire form.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off">  

<input type="text" name="text1" autocomplete="off">
```

But remember: This is a very useful feature, before turning it off make sure that it is essential to turn it off

Comment: +1 and here's a [link](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/481.cfm) about that. and because it breaks html validation, you can do this dynamically like this, `$('input').attr('autocomplete','off')` - cheers!

Comment: I tried both AutoCompleteType="Disabled" and AutoCompleteType="None" but still it keeps history. As I mentioned this is Textbox control in ASP.NET page not HTML.

Comment: @Naraza - I think because it already cached it before. Try clearing the cache and/or try this [textbox.autocompletetype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autocompletetype.aspx) of asp.net

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to change the input type from `password` to `text` ?

```
$('#yourField').attr('type', 'text')
```

Comment: This doesn't work, jQuery doesn't allow you to change the type attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the "type" attribute. There is some jquery plugins for that.

This one is very simple to use: 
http://unwrongest.com/projects/show-password/